# Webform: Remove automatically generated empty composite item in results edit

Tags: webforms, 9

When I enable, submit, and edit results in the [webform example composite module](https://drupal.org/project/webform), an extra item is automatically generated.

[image]

I'd like to keep "Add 1 more items", but remove the automatically generated "empty" composite item. I've done this with fields with this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hide Last Item in tag widget.
  $field_names = [
    'field_tags',
    'field_tags_two',
  ];
  foreach ($field_names as $field_name) {
    if (isset($form[$field_name])) {
      $max_delta = $form[$field_name]['widget']['#max_delta'];
      if (!$form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity()
          ->isNew() && isset($form[$field_name]['widget'][1])) {
        unset($form[$field_name]['widget'][$max_delta]);
        $form[$field_name]['widget']['#max_delta'] = $max_delta - 1;
      }
    }
    // Unset the Add another item button.
    unset($form[$field_name]['widget']['add_more']);
  }
}
```

How do I do this with webform composite elements?

Answer (score 0):

The empty_items property needs to be set to 0. There may be a configuration for this, but I couldn't find it. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm $form_object */
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();

  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
  $webform_submission = $form_object->getEntity();

  $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();
  foreach ($data as $element_key => $element_value) {
    $element = $webform->getElement($element_key);
    if (!empty($element['#webform_key'])) {
      if ($element['#webform_key'] == 'my_composite') {
        $form['elements']['container']['my_composite']['#empty_items'] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```